# JS Geolocation and Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, local-storage

this is my code 
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mjFbd89fzF

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

    }
    if (typeof (localStorage) != "undefined") {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            localStorage.setItem('latitude', position.coords.latitude);
            localStorage.setItem('longitude', position.coords.longitude);
        });

        $('#location').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('latitude') + ' ' + localStorage.getItem('longitude');

    }
});
```

here's the HTML

```
<BODY>
        <h1>you're here</h1>

        <h2 id="location"></h2>

</BODY>
```

i get prompted to share my location but the h2 tag doesn't get updated even if the position is stored in localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous function and will executed after `$('#location')`., you can store it in local storage but this data will be available after second page load, you can set `$('#location')` in `getCurrentPosition` or you can use `Deferred`.

```
#1
$(document).ready(function () {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {}

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
   $('#location').html(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
  });
});

#2
$(document).ready(function () {
  var d = $.Deferred();

  if (navigator.geolocation) {}

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    d.resolve(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  });

  d.done(function(latitude, longitude) { 
    $('#location').html(latitude + ' ' + longitude);
  });
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/xaloke/1/edit?html,js,output)